# COBOL table structure and output

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to userstand how this works:

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 PAY-TABLE.
    05 PAY-VALUES OCCURS 25 TIMES PIC 9(3)V99.
01 WORKING-VALUES.
    05 SUB PIC 9(2) VALUE ZERO.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
INITIALIZE-ROUTINE.
INITIALIZE PAY-TABLE

MAINLINE-ROUTINE.
PERFORM LOAD-TABLE
    VARYING SUB FROM 1
        BY 1
              UNTIL SUB>10.
DISPLAY-ROUTINE.
DISPLAY PAY-VALUE (SUB)

LOAD-TABLE.
MOVE SUB TO PAY-VALUE (SUB).
```

I have this code as a review code in the book. There are several questions according to this code, with answers, however, I don't really understand why should it be exactly this answer.

> 1. The DISPLAY statement will display the value _____ on the monitor.
>      Answer: unknown
> 2. When the value of SUB in the PERFORM statement is equal to 9, the value in PAY-VALUE (SUB), before the PERFORM executes, will be equal to:
>      Answer:10
> 3. When the LOAD-TABLE routine has executed for the last time, the value in PAY-VALUE (25) will be:
>      Answer: 26

I've tried to read tutorials about tables but still don't understand how this example works.

Comment: There must be code missing - the sample should not compile because 1) missing headers and 2 missing periods.
Leaving this away I still would say that *all* given answers are wrong.

Comment: @SimonSobisch, thank you for your answers! These answers are given to me and this part of code is given to me...

Comment: @SimonSobisch, for 1st question there are also variants: 5; 0; 10; 4. For 2nd: 12; 0; 7; none. For 3rd: 25; 0; 10; none. Do you think some of these are correct?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Abc: leaving the syntax errors mentioned in the first comment away: yes one of the answers given is correct for each question - just not the ones you gave. In general: see the comment from cschneid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that much of this depends on the environment -- some COBOL compilers behave differently and there are also variances between platforms.  (I've had a lot of fun with this porting code from HP3000 COBOL to Linux NetCOBOL.)  But generally speaking...

1) The book may say the answer is "unknown" because compilers may initialize things differently.  `INITIALIZE PAY-TABLE` may set each instance of **PAY-VALUE** to zero or it may set **PAY-TABLE** (the 125 byte character field that is comprised of the 25 **PAY-VALUE**s) to spaces.  What it should be, however, (as in the former case,) is zero.

2) This is incorrect.  Again, there is the possibility of variance (due to the reason mentioned in #1) but it should be zero.  Because nothing has happened to **PAY-VALUE** yet (before the PERFORM for SUB=9), it would still be the value to which it had been initialized.

3) As in #2, with the same caveats, the answer should be zero.  Because the `LOAD-TABLE` paragraph is only performed until **SUB** becomes greater than 10, **PAY-VALUE (25)** will never change from its initialized value.

Note also that the program is poorly written -- without a `STOP RUN.` at the end of the `MAINLINE-ROUTINE`, the program will continue on and execute the `DISPLAY-ROUTINE` and `LOAD-TABLE` paragraphs one last time.

There are also, a number of typos, most notably the definition of **PAY-VALUES** (with an **S**) and the usage of **PAY-VALUE** (no **S**).

Here is a sample run (I added displays before and after the `MOVE` statement in `LOAD-TABLE` and after the `PERFORM LOAD-TABLE` statement has completed.  Note the extra displays.)

```
Before move -- Sub: 01   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00100

Before move -- Sub: 02   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00200

Before move -- Sub: 03   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00300

Before move -- Sub: 04   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00400

Before move -- Sub: 05   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00500

Before move -- Sub: 06   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00600

Before move -- Sub: 07   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00700

Before move -- Sub: 08   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00800

Before move -- Sub: 09   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 00900

Before move -- Sub: 10   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 01000

Completed Perform of LOAD-TABLE.
PAY-VALUE(25): 00000
00000

Before move -- Sub: 11   PV: 00000
After move  --           PV: 01100
```

Bear in mind that the **PAY-VALUE** values show as hundreds (e.g., 00100 instead of 1) because the field is defined as 9(03)V99 meaning there is an implied decimal place and two digits to the right of it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Only a compiler which does not comply to a COBOL Standard would have a variant result with INITIALIZE, I think you may as well discount the possibility of that.